# Using variable-controlled logging level in Python logger

Tags: python, logging, dynamic, user-defined, log-level

I want to write a function that will get the requested logging level from the user, i.e. something like:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()

def func(log_level: <Type?>):
    logger.log_level("everything is bad")
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [`log()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.log) of a logger, which takes a level as well as a format string and arguments.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()

def func(log_level: int, message: str):
    logger.log(log_level, message)
    
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(levelname)-8s %(message)s')

func(logging.DEBUG, 'message at DEBUG level')
func(logging.INFO, 'message at INFO level')
func(logging.CRITICAL, 'message at CRITICAL level')
```

Which prints

```
DEBUG    message at DEBUG level
INFO     message at INFO level
CRITICAL message at CRITICAL level
```

when run.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this. It first looks a little verbose, but you can easily add addtional handlers (maybe some that log to a file...)

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.StreamHandler() #you can also use FileHandler here, but then you need to specify a path
handler.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)

LOG_FORMAT = "%(levelname)s: %(message)s"
formatter = logging.Formatter(LOG_FORMAT)

handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.log(logging.CRITICAL, "your logging message 1") #==> CRITICAL: your logging message 1
logger.log(logging.WARN,     "your logging message 2") #==> WARN: your logging message 2
```

Note 1: `LOG_FORMAT` is defined according to the [logging-documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#formatters)

Note 2: the logging levels (`logging.DEBUG`, `logging.INFO`...) are explained [here](https://www.logicmonitor.com/blog/python-logging-levels-explained). You can also use integer values accordingly:

| logging.XX | Value |
| --- | --- |
| NOTSET | 0 |
| DEBUG | 10 |
| INFO | 20 |
| WARN | 30 |
| ERROR | 40 |
| CRITICAL | 50 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use the context manager, I quote for the documentation "There are times when it would be useful to temporarily change the logging configuration and revert it back after doing something. For this, a context manager is the most obvious way of saving and restoring the logging context. Here is a simple example of such a context manager, which allows you to optionally change the logging level and add a logging handler purely in the scope of the context manager:"

```
import logging
import sys

class LoggingContext:
    def __init__(self, logger, level=None, handler=None, close=True):
        self.logger = logger
        self.level = level
        self.handler = handler
        self.close = close

    def __enter__(self):
        if self.level is not None:
            self.old_level = self.logger.level
            self.logger.setLevel(self.level)
        if self.handler:
            self.logger.addHandler(self.handler)

    def __exit__(self, et, ev, tb):
        if self.level is not None:
            self.logger.setLevel(self.old_level)
        if self.handler:
            self.logger.removeHandler(self.handler)
        if self.handler and self.close:
            self.handler.close()
        # implicit return of None => don't swallow exceptions
```

Exactly in the documentation, it is here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-a-context-manager-for-selective-logging .
You can also rewrite any of the sample code snippets from: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-logging-in-multiple-modules .